# how to separate the mixed models, and fit separate linear models

Tags: r, linear-regression, mixed-models

I am trying to fit a linear model and separate the mixed models. Then fit separate linear models to `model_steeper` and `model_flatter`. First, I create training samples with Input >= 5 and separate the points

```
nSample<-length(data$Input)
Train.Sample<-data.frame(trainInput=data$Input,trainOutput=rep(NA,nSample))
Train.Sample.Steeper<-data.frame(trainSteepInput=data$Input,trainSteepOutput=rep(NA,nSample))  
Train.Sample.Flatter<-data.frame(trainFlatInput=data$Input,trainFlatOutput=rep(NA,nSample))   
head(cbind(data,Train.Sample,Train.Sample.Steeper,Train.Sample.Flatter))
```

and the result is:

```
    dput(head(cbind(data,Train.Sample,Train.Sample.Steeper,Train.Sample.Flatter)))
structure(list(Output = c(0.430030802963404, -0.387872242279496, 
-0.773463398992163, 3.47962503801818, -1.18311295613965, -0.534018180113726
), Input = c(-0.707348558586091, -0.596670078579336, -1.55126970726997, 
2.00976222474128, -1.69353070948273, -0.437843651510775), trainInput = c(-0.707348558586091, 
-0.596670078579336, -1.55126970726997, 2.00976222474128, -1.69353070948273, 
-0.437843651510775), trainOutput = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    trainSteepInput = c(-0.707348558586091, -0.596670078579336, 
    -1.55126970726997, 2.00976222474128, -1.69353070948273, -0.437843651510775
    ), trainSteepOutput = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), trainFlatInput = c(-0.707348558586091, 
    -0.596670078579336, -1.55126970726997, 2.00976222474128, 
    -1.69353070948273, -0.437843651510775), trainFlatOutput = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then, I tried:

```
Train.Sample.Steep.lm <- lm(trainSteepOutput ~ trainSteepInput, Train.Sample.Steeper)
```

But the error is:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases
```

I do not know what to do next. Does any one know this?

Comment: Your dependent variable is just NAs, what else would you expect?

Comment: thank you, so what should I do to split the linear model into two separate model using this linearmodel <-lm(Output~Input,data)

Comment: I don't know, all I can tell is that your `trainSteepOutput` variable has nothing but NA, thus leading to the error. I would look upstream for what the issue is that leads to that variable having nothing but NAs.